# Android: Change color of line below ActionBar

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I want to change the color of the orange line below the ActionBar.

[image: http://s14.directupload.net/images/130911/3suejbj2.png]

I've tried a few things but nothing has helped so far.

The current theme on my Galaxy S2 is an orange theme.
So changing the theme, also changes the line.
But I don´t know how to get access to that line, in order to change the color.

Comment: Use Action bar style generator http://jgilfelt.github.io/android-actionbarstylegenerator/#name=example&compat=holo&theme=light&actionbarstyle=solid&backColor=E4E4E4%2C100&secondaryColor=D6D6D6%2C100&tertiaryColor=F2F2F2%2C100&accentColor=33B5E5%2C100

Answer (score 12):

You can use This code for achieving your purpose.

background.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#ff0000" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:bottom="5dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#ffffff" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

styles.xml

```
<resources>
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo">
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/AppTheme.ActionBar</item>
        <item name="android:background">#ffffff</item>
        <item name="android:colorBackground">#ffffff</item>
    </style>
    <style name="AppTheme.ActionBar" parent="android:Widget.ActionBar">
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/background</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

These codes are suitable when you have not any options menu like image shows in question, if you have options menu you must customize your option menu items background.

If you have Option menu below code is suitable:

```
<resources>
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light">
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/AppTheme.ActionBar</item>
        <item name="android:popupMenuStyle">@style/AppTheme.PopUpMenu</item>
    </style>
    <style name="AppTheme.ActionBar" parent="android:Widget.ActionBar">
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/background</item>
    </style>
    <style name="AppTheme.PopUpMenu" parent="android:Widget.Holo.Light.ListPopupWindow">
        <item name="android:popupBackground">@drawable/background</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

Comment: When I use the PopUpMenu style here, my action bar text is gone.

Answer (score 4):

There is A simpler way than this (Creating Bunch of Styles).
Refering to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20277867/how-to-custom-the-thin-line-below-actionbar-using-appcompat-in-android) . Just set

```
getActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(null);
```

This will Remove the line from Your Action Bar

Answer (score 1):

I used this ^_^ and it is 100% working:

```
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    Drawable res = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ab_transparent_example);
    getActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(res);
```

and JUST USE THIS [image: .9.png]

Answer (score 0):

In my case, in my application, I used the Holo theme.

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo">
       ...
 </style>
```

Background toolbar is set through the property.

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/ActionBarStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="ActionBarStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/action_bar_background</item>
</style>
```

Standard Holo action bar background is nine-patch drawable like this:

[nine patch drawable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e9gwT.png)

So, if you want to change the color of the bottom line, you need to create a new nine-patch drawable.
[Create Resizable Bitmaps (9-Patch files)](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/draw9patch.html)

Put the file in the folder drawable (example drawable-xxhdpi) and specify the path to the file in the theme.