# How to change the blue line color to other colors under the sherlockactionbar

Tags: java, android, actionbarsherlock

I want to change the blue color line under the `ActionBarSherlock` to green color or other colors. I have tried so many ways to accomplish it but ending up failure, the core part is the blue line always exist.

Could anyone has the good way to solve it?

In addition, I prefer to make it by code instead of the generator project recommended  by others.

Please instruct me in a detail code or step,any advice would be appreciated,Thanks in advance.

Comment: Read this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking -- PLEASE.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code sample:

```
actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(null);
```

Comment: Thinks to your apply first,but if i do so,how can i change the color ?please tell me in detail

Comment: Check this out : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18736300/android-change-color-of-line-below-actionbar

Comment: not this,what I want to change is the color of the actionbarshelock indicator color,I meant the default blue line