# How to change action bar style based on string.xml value

Tags: android, xml

I need to change the action bar based on some changes done on strings.xml file.

In strings.xml

```
<string  name="app_url">http://example.com</string>
```

If i hard code to new url then ActionBar should be different.

```
<string  name="app_url">http://temparary.com</string>
```

Is there any way to change action bar style in oncreate method of my class.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

First in onCreate get string app_url

```
String str = getString(R.string.app_url);
ActionBar actionbar = getActionBar();

if(str.equalsIgnoreCase("link1")) {

    //style your actionbar according to link1
} else {
    //style your actionbar according to link2
}
```

EDIT

To Add sprite on Actionbar you can create a 9 patch image and set that image as a BackgroundDrawable of your ActionBar

like

```
Drawable res = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.your_image);
getActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(res);
```

Comment: can you add a code to style actionbar. i need to add stripes on actionbar.

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18736300/android-change-color-of-line-below-actionbar